# Django static images aren't displayed

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I have deployed one of my project with free version in 'pythonanywhere', but the static images aren't visible in there.

While testing in local everything seems to be working but on deploying and adding static images to it, the images aren't visible there. Please help me find what went wrong here.

In my django templates I used these tags to show images

```
                    <div class="card-image">
                    <img src="{{cat.category_image.get_photo_url }}">
                    </div>
```

Or provide me some documentation links to have a look into development issues.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for django static files in production is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/).

Make sure you run `python manage.py collectstatic` before you deploy as the local server stores static files in a separate location to the production server. Again, [here's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic) the documentation on the `collectstatic` function.

Comment: As you're using PythonAnywhere, [this platform-specific help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles) also has useful information about how to configure stuff there.

Comment: Thanks Giles. It did collect the static some files.
But somehow images are still not visible. Is my img tag correct to fetch the image urls?

Comment: The img tag looks OK, but perhaps the static files mappings you set up on the "Web" page inside PythonAnywhere are incorrect?  Perhaps you could share a screenshot of what you've done there.  Also, double-check if you reloaded the site using the button at the top of the "Web" page after setting up static file mappings, because they don't take effect until you do that.

Answer (score 0):

@Giles, cant add an image to the comment. Here is the screenshot from pythonanywhere

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are mapping /static/ and /media/ to your home directory. Take a look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingStaticFiles

Comment: Also, you should not post the image as an answer. You could edit your question.

Comment: Thanks Filip, thanks Giles. My static file was pointing to somewhere else. Now it looks working.